# ReferenceError: window is not defined in React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, web, npm

I installed "react-speech" package for my application to build text to speech functionality. But while importing the package I'm getting the following error. I did enough googling to resolve this issue but unable to do so. Any help is much appreciated.

Error:

```
ReferenceError: window is not defined

    at new SpeakTTS (/Users/moharja/Project/React-master/node_modules/speak-tts/lib/speak-tts.js:22:48)

    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/moharja/Project/React-master/src/components/Judgement/Landing/RightBar/Top/top.component.jsx:24:16)

    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1201:30)

    at Module._compile (/Users/moharja/Project/React-master/node_modules/pirates/lib/index.js:99:24)

    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1221:10)

    at Object.newLoader [as .jsx] (/Users/moharja/Project/React-master/node_modules/pirates/lib/index.js:104:7)

    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1050:32)

    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:938:14)

    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1090:19)

    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:75:18)

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! errno 1

npm ERR! lm-suite-react@0.1.0 start: `rimraf build && webpack --mode production --progress --profile --color && node index.js`

npm ERR! Exit status 1

npm ERR!

npm ERR! Failed at the lm-suite-react@0.1.0 start script.

npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.



npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR!     /Users/moharja/.npm/_logs/2020-10-19T17_30_09_085Z-debug.log `
```

Note: I tried to use different packages too instead of "react-speech". But the same error is occurring.

Comment: If your running this in node, yes there is no window object in node.js..  I assume SpeakTTS is a Browser component, so it won't run in node.js.

Comment: what is your start script?

Answer (score 4):

This library is not compatible with SSR (Server Side Rendering).
I guess you are trying to do that with, webpack.

```
if (typeof window === 'undefined') {
  global.window = {}
}
```

I guess this might not throw any error, remember you have to declared this before you import the library.

Comment: Throws the following error: "Attempt to assign to const or readonly variable"

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about the `react-speech` package. But I encountered something similar while trying to bundle one of my modules for browser using webpack (bundle process runs on `node` and `window` is undefined in that `context`).
This is what I used:

```
let win
try {
  win = window
} catch (error) {
  // suppress the Reference error and assign an empty object to win
  // this should not be reachable in actual browser as window 
  // will be defined in that context.

  win = {} 
}
```

We are doing this just so that webpack builds the module without throwing.

```
... 
// replace window with win

// window.fetch(...)
win.fetch(...)
```

Since you are trying to use a library maintained by someone else, you could either try to build it on your own, or you could raise an issue for the package maintainers.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to highlight that encountering this problem in `docusaurus` is quite common after you've built the application. To address this issue, you can resolve it by enclosing your code with the condition `if (typeof window !== "undefined")` within the [`<Root>`](https://docusaurus.io/docs/swizzling#wrapper-your-site-with-root) component. This component is rendered at the top of the React tree, ensuring that when you use `window` in any of the child components, you won't encounter any issues.

> If the Root component does not exist in your app just create it under `src/theme`

src/theme/Root.js

```js
import React from "react";
export default function Root({ children }) {
  if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
    return (
      <>
        {children}
      </>
    );
  }
  return null;
}
```